# Get all class names from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, class-names

What I am trying to achieve is just to get all class names which are used with a certain element.

The problem is that when I use my various methods to get the class names, only the first class is being returned.

Lets say I have a table, where each `<td>` tags have the classes `classOne classPart1 classThree`

and will thus look something like this:

```
<table id='gridMain'>
    <tr>
        <td class = 'classOne classPart1 classThree'></td>
        <td class = 'classOne classPart2 classThree'></td>
        <td class = 'classOne classPart3 classThree'></td>
        <td class = 'classOne classPart4 classThree'></td>
        <td class = 'classOne classPart5 classThree'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I've tried is the following:

```
var classArray = [];
$("#gridMain .classOne").each(function (ix, element) 
{
    //Example 1 
    alert($(this).attr('class'));

    //Example 2
    $($(this).attr('class').split(' ')).each(function() 
    { 
        classArray.push(this);
    });

    //Example 3
    alert(this.className);
}
```

In Example 1 only 'classOne is returned'.
In Example 2, I try to split the classes and create an array, with the same result. The Array Length is 1. Only 'classOne is returned'.
And in example 3, only classOne is returned...

**Anyone know why this is happening?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: looks fine here http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/Stmmw/.. your were missing `)` end bracketin the question which i think is not the case...

Comment: It does work yes, which is strange, because it's not working in my script locally.

Comment: make sure.. none of the other script is breaking your code.. it will be hard to help you without seeing your other code

Comment: I've found the problem. The order in which I instantiated my code was wrong. By the time I tried to retrieve the classes, they have not yet been instantiated. A mistake on my part...